# How can you access files without a explicit link?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess, permissions

I have found in my server, that some files are stored inside the webroot, for example

```
example.com/files/longnamewithcode_1234293182391823212313231230812.pdf
```

They are stored for a web app and hace sensible info on them.

If you access `example.com/files` you get an empty `index.html`, so you can't directly scan the directory. Anyway, I'm concerned about this: I feel that it is not safe and I would like to know what kind of attacks could be made to access the files. I understand that some brute force attack would be possible, but with the long code names I guess it's a less big problem.

Finally, I would say that the correct way is storing the files outside the web folder and return them with PHP, but I'm not sure I'll be able to have access to the code to change this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have to make the files accessible from webroot by the webserver you can't really make it more safe than use sufficient amount of entropy in the file names, but that still not account for simply sharing a the links by users that get a hold of them somehow.

If you want to implement the permission checking inside php take a look into the various `X-Sendfile` implementations on popular webservers like, [mod_xsendfile](https://tn123.org/mod_xsendfile/) (apache), [XSendfile](http://wiki.nginx.org/XSendfile) (nginx) or [X-LIGHTTPD-send-file](http://redmine.lighttpd.net/projects/1/wiki/X-LIGHTTPD-send-file) (lighttpd). This allows you to use the webserver to serve the file basically as efficiently as simply accessing it from the webroot after you validated the accessing user.

Comment: Ok, I´m going for something like this. I´m sure that there are more correct ways to do this right, like the options you offer, but I found this accidentally in an app I don´t have responsability on. Even then, I found necessary to at least, ask about this issue :P 

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

have you considered an [.htaccess](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Htaccess) file to restrict who is allowed to access those sensible files? you tagged it, but i'm not sure why you are not using it. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to block everything in the folder you can use an .htaccess file to block all connections.

Try

```
deny from all
```

in the .htaccess file in that directory. This will deny all access to anything in that directory including the index file.

Answer (score 0):

The question is

> Are the files supposed to be accessed by users freely?

If yes, don't worry about those files too much (as long as they're not writeable).

If no, i.e. users have to be logged in to download them, move them out from the publicly accessible folder and deeper into the application. Write a php script that will manage the permissions for the file i.e. `/download?file_id=1`.